# Blocking the first number in a text field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text input binded to a variable that contains a 5 digits number. How can I block the first digit so only the other 4 are editable?

Currently I have this: `ng-model="my_var" ng-pattern="/^\d{5}$/"`

Please note that the value is two-way binded, which means I'm showing it and the user can edit /save it.

Comment: How do you get the first digit in the first place?

Comment: @Banana-In-Black The value is guaranteed to have a 5 digits number when received from the server after a ```GET```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution (you will need probably tweak it a little bit for your particular needs):

```
app.directive("filterInput", function () {

    return {
        require: 'ngModel', // controller to ng-model needed
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            var unchanged = attrs.filterInput;
            var regex = /^\d{0,5}$/; // the RegExp (in more generic solution could be passed from outside)

            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) { // adding new $parser

                 if(inputValue[0] != unchanged){ // if the first digit is different from what it should be set value as the first digit
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(unchanged);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                    return unchanged;
                }

                if(inputValue.length > 5){ // trim the input if it is longer than five -- it is not generic at all
                    var rv = inputValue.substring(0,5);

                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(rv);
                    modelCtrl.$render();

                    return rv;
                }



                var transformedInput = regex.exec(inputValue);

                if (transformedInput != null) { // check if pattern exists
                    transformedInput = transformedInput[0];
                }
                else {
                    transformedInput = unchanged; // if not set the value to the not changeable part
                }

                if (transformedInput != inputValue) { // re-render if value changed
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput); 
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And how to use it:

```
<p>var: {{my_var}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="my_var" filter-input="1"/>
```

<kbd>[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQ9CuPp32rP8T3ULlWXw?p=preview)</kbd>

Btw: it will allow to pass only digits :-)

Comment: This segfaults with: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @alexandernst if you want to use it with ng-pattern -- as ng-pattern set $modelValue as undefined. you can try to change the priority of the directive to be higher than the priority of the ng-pattern, or resign from ng-pattern altogether, as it is impossible to put invalid input. did you looked at the plnkr?

Comment: So... I remove the ng-pattern, and now it won't let me type anything further than 1 digit. Are you sure this is working?

Comment: @alexandernst did you look here: [http://plnkr.co/edit/EbhC6k8RwfPovqeSQprc?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/EbhC6k8RwfPovqeSQprc?p=preview)? (in chorme it works fine)

Comment: Yes, I'm looking right there. If I run it as-is it will enter in some kind of error-loop. It will eventually quit the loop saying what I already mentioned in my first reply.

Comment: @alexandernst wow, it is so, so strange -- when I open this url in chrome the correct version is loaded in firefox some previous garbage... (no idea way) I forked this plnkr and now it works both in Chrome and Firefox. I updated the url in the question but here it is: [http://plnkr.co/edit/GQ9CuPp32rP8T3ULlWXw?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQ9CuPp32rP8T3ULlWXw?p=preview).

Comment: @alexandernst Probably (99%) the issue was because I did not save the plnkr while editing (in chrome) -- and the most recent version were loaded from local cache; whereas at yours machine and in Firefox, we get the version from the plnkr's servers. Sorry for this omission from my side.

Comment: Indeed, it "works" now. And I wrote "it works" because this is not doing any of what I asked. Even further, that entire code can the trimmed down to my "ng-pattern" rule.

Comment: @alexandernst could you bit more precise what you mean by this? You wanted: *I have a text input binded to a variable that contains a 5 digits number. How can I block the first digit so only the other 4 are editable?* -- so my solution keeps the first digit un-editable and allows editing the remaining 4 **digits** (it is exactly what you asked for). Now, please show me as a plnkr how you can achieve the same using just `ng-pattern`.

Comment: Your plnkr isn't doing that. I'm able to freely write whichever 5 numbers I want (including changing the first one). *Please* refresh/clear cache/whatever and see what your plnkr is actually doing.

Comment: @alexandernst no idea what are you talking about -- double checked with my second laptop [there could not be any cache issue there.]. Do you follow this link: [http://plnkr.co/edit/GQ9CuPp32rP8T3ULlWXw?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQ9CuPp32rP8T3ULlWXw?p=preview)? Anyway: I updated the question with html part so you can re-create it at yours.

Comment: Steps I'm following:  1) Visit http://plnkr.co/edit/GQ9CuPp32rP8T3ULlWXw?p=preview  2) Click on the input 3) Hit the left arrow  4) Write some numbers  5) The first number isn't 1 anymore.

Comment: @alexandernst yes indeed -- did not predict such scenario: but now it works fine -- check it again. Btw. it is just a seed of solution / an inspiration you can follow and modify on your own.

Comment: Glad that could help -- learnt myself a bit doing so:-) (and sorry for these issues with plnkr)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom directive that would work in conjunction with ngModel.

It could use the parser/formatter to modify the value read/printed.

Read more about it here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController ($formatters and $parsers)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best solution but it works:

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="my_var" maxlength="5">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.my_var = '1';
$scope.$watch('my_var', function(){
  if($scope.my_var.length != 1){
    if($scope.my_var.length == 0){
      $scope.my_var = '1';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for